# Windows program for filtering available fonts (like Adobe Type Manager)

Tags: windows, fonts

I'm looking for a program (for Windows 7/8.1) which would be able to filter installed fonts in Windows so when I use some other programs and I'm trying to choose of some installed fonts, I wouldn't see everything installed but just some part of it. I think example tell it better:

i.e.:
I'm using Adobe Photoshop and I need to choose some grunge font for poster. So I download some fonts, which could look good, I install them and I want to try them in particular image in PS with applied effects. But I don't remember every name of downloaded font, so everytime I have to check the name and then choose it from a list of about houndred fonts. Which is very slow and annoying. But I need list just from these right-downloaded fonts.

So I need a program, where I could check, that I want to use profile (or folder) "grunge" and then I would have list of available fonts just these what I need.

Long time ago I used Adobe Type Manager and it was able to do it. But Adobe discontinued it's development and support and it doesn't work in new versions of Windows. Since then I wasn't able to find anything which have the same ability.

So if you've found some program which can do it, I would really appreciate it. If you have some idea how to reach the same goal some other way, it would be better than nothing.

Answer (score 0):

After spending awhile looking around, I finally found a program with exactly this feature. `Suitcase Fusion 5`. It can easily activate and deactivate fonts. It goes even further. I can activate and deactivate fonts which aren't in system Fonts folder. And finally, it has a plugin to Adobe Photoshop where I can list fonts in a group. It's not free, but it's worth it.